# Trying to write haskell in emacs but not working, get error 'The Haskell process 'haskell' has died. Restart?"

Tags: emacs, packages

Trying to write haskell in emacs but not working, get error 'The Haskell process 'haskell' has died. Restart?" I installed the packages for haskell but somehow the code cannot be complied. Can someone please tell me how to fix it? I check several websites I think one of them might make some sense. I didn't see any content of ghci is shown. Might be the problem that Emacs cannot locate the haskell compiler but I don't know how to fix it.